# Change link color if body/background color is white

Tags: javascript, css

Links on our website in an element with the class "elementor-text-editor" are styled with this color rule:

```
.elementor-text-editor a {
    color: #e9741f;
}
```

How can we automatically change the link color to #ffd329 if the link appears on a white background? (if the link appears in an element, such as a div, with a color other than #fff, we would not want the link color to change)

Comment: You'll likely need something like `LESS` or `SASS`...

Comment: Or `SCSS`: https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/

Comment: You cannot do that with plain CSS. You'll need either LESS, SASS, SCSS or JavaScript to handle that logic.

Comment: Hi, irishrunner16: let me know if my answer helped you in any way!  Hope it has!

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, use the [**Child Combinator (`>`) Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) to color a URL differently based on what container it is in.  So, for example, you would have a `#white-background` and `#blue-background` `div`'s, each differently colored.  Then you'd be able to affect just one background with...

```
#blue-background > .elementor-text-editor { ... }
```

What happens within the `...` will only affect links with a *blue background*.  Demo...

```css
.elementor-text-editor {
    color: #e9741f
}

#blue-background > .elementor-text-editor {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#white-background {
  background-color:white;
}

#blue-background {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="white-background">
<a class="elementor-text-editor" href="wikipedia.org">link1</a>
</div>

<div id="blue-background">
<a class="elementor-text-editor" href="wikipedia.org">link2</a>
</div>
```

**Disclaimer:** This will only work for `static`-positioned elements.  If you have `absolute` elements, or anything fancy like that, you'll need to think of another approach.  I don't see enough detail to give further advice, though.